# How to use xlookup for value between two number in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of time attendance value and want to look for time attendance between two time points of specific ID as the image. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Dynaic Arrays you can use

```
=FILTER(B2:B9,(A2:A9=E3)*(B2:B9>=D2)*(B2:B9<=F2),"")
```

to return *all* values that match (Spills)

Or

```
=@FILTER(B2:B9,(A2:A9=E3)*(B2:B9>=D2)*(B2:B9<=F2),"")
```

to return only the first match

Answer (score -2):

Find values in range or table.
=XLOOKUP (lookup, lookup_array, return_array, [not_found], [match_mode], [search_mode])